# Как с помощью регулярного выражения получить данные из <script>........</script>?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить данные с сайта из тегов `<script type="application/ld+json" nonce="Xndz9UyuK7juH/A/Cqp9qQ">данные</script>`, значение nonce всегда разные.

Мое выражение не работает:

```
preg_match('|<script\s+type=[\'"]application/ld+json[\'"]\s+nonce=[\'"][a-z0-9][\'"]>(.*)</script>|mi', $url, $result);
print $result[1];
```

Как правильно получить json из `<script type="application/ld+json" nonce="Xndz9UyuK7juH/A/Cqp9qQ">данные</script>`?

Что лучше использовать file_get_contents или cURL?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вот самый простой вариант:

```
<?php
$url = '<script type="application/ld+json" nonce="Xndz9UyuK7juH/A/Cqp9qQ">данные</script>';

preg_match('/<script[^>]+>(.*)<\/script>/mi', $url, $result);

print_r($result);
```

[Выполнить PHP код](https://phpize.online/?phpses=a2ec48858f4d203e310aae8f6f575d46&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)